# I can not get data from db in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I Watched series buld a cms in codeigniter on tutlus.

page:

```
public function get_no_parents() {
    // Fetch pages without parents
    $this->db->select('id', 'title');
    $this->db->where('parent_id', 0);
    $pages = parent::get();

    // Return key => value pair array
    $array = array(
    0 => 'No parent');
    if(count($pages)) {
        foreach($pages as $page) {
        $array[$page->id] = $page->title;
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

MY_Model.php

```
public function get($id = NULL, $single = FALSE){

if ($id != NULL) {
    $filter = $this->_primary_filter;
    $id = $filter($id);
    $this->db->where($this->_primary_key, $id);
    $method = 'row';
}
elseif($single == TRUE) {
        $method = 'row';
}
else {
$method = 'result';
}

    if (!count($this->db->ar_orderby)) {
        $this->db->order_by($this->_order_by);
    }
    return $this->db->get($this->_table_name)->$method();
}
}
```

when i get data, result return: 0 => 'No parent', The correct is: 0 => No parent, 1 => Homepage, 2 => About.

database:

```
id  | title    |  parent_id
 1  | Homepage |    0
 2  | About    |    0
```

Comment: did you print last query?

Comment: it's: <td><select name="parent_id">
<option value="0" selected="selected">No parent</option>
<option value="1"></option>
<option value="2"></option> . error message:  Undefined property: stdClass::$title

Comment: i mean `echo $this->db->last_query();` after ` $pages = parent::get();`

Comment: SELECT `id` FROM (`pages`) WHERE `parent_id` = 0 ORDER BY `order`.

Comment: did you run this query in your phpmyadmin?

Comment: @kumar_v: OK,  `$this->db->select('id, title');`  do not: `$this->db->select('id', 'title');` Thanks you.